# TCP socket over internet with hard coded IPs

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, server, client

I want to test a very simple client-server app that would send a basic message using a TCP socket over the internet between 2 devices. I don't need a server to find the IP addresses and all the hole punching work behind that, for now I just want to hard code the external IP to first see if what I'm working on is worth pursuing. Right now I have everything working on local network, but nothing works over the internet. I'm certain I'm putting the right external IP and not the local one. This is the piece of code I have on the C++ side (sorry for the formatting, but stackoverflow didn't want to accept the code otherwise):

```
struct sockaddr_in server_address_tcp;
memset(&server_address_tcp, 0, sizeof(server_address_tcp));
server_address_tcp.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address_tcp.sin_port = htons(19663);
server_address_tcp.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("my ip");
char opt_val = '1';
setsockopt(pContext->tcp_sock, IPPROTO_TCP, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_val, sizeof opt_val);
if ((bind(pContext->tcp_sock, (struct sockaddr*) & server_address_tcp,
sizeof(server_address))) < 0)
ERR("Could not bind TCP socket\n");
}
int err = ::listen(pContext->tcp_sock, 128);
if (err < 0) {
ERR("Could not listen on TCP socket\n");
pContext->errcode = LIBUDP_SOCKET_ERROR;
return LIBUDPSEND_ERR;
}
LOG("Waiting for TCP connection");
struct sockaddr_in client;
socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client);
pContext->tcp_client_sock = accept(pContext->tcp_sock, (struct sockaddr*) & client, &client_len);
if (pContext->tcp_sock < 0) {
ERR("Could not establish new connection\n");
pContext->errcode = LIBUDP_SOCKET_ERROR;
return LIBUDPSEND_ERR;
}
```

I have a Java code that does a send to this c++ part, the bind and listen go through, and the accept never goes through, it just hangs there. On local it goes through, over internet it doesn't. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We can assume that "my ip" is just a place-holder for a properly formatted address, yes? If not, start there. What kind of networking hardware, and possibly firewalls do you have in the way? Have you tracked what is happening with a packet analyzer like Wireshark?

Comment: Yes it's a proper address. I'm traying Wireshark to see how it behaves.

Comment: If you have two endpoints that can each only make an outbound connection but not accept an inbound connection, you *do* need hole punching. Have you ensured that the "server" end can accept an inbound connection from the Internet using manual port forwarding, UPnP, or some similar mechanism?

Comment: i had the same problem when i did a code that send from java to python over internet and i needed to do a portfowarding, i don't know if you know portfowarding but it's a system that when the rooter receive data from a certain port you tell him if it's on port 80 for exemple give this connextion to this computer, also the problem that i had was that over internet the data wasn't receive until the connextion was  close.   ì hope that my experience help you if never you have some question please tell me` i currently have this problem with webscoket in JS i know the problem :-)

Comment: you use a public ip from the rooter like this one to connect `86.205.119.30`